# Vim autoload doesn`t work

Tags: vimrc, vim-windows, autoload

I've created a `~/.vimrc` file that uses `plug.vim`.

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'something'
call plug#end()
```

I also downloaded `plug.vim` and put in the folder `~/.vim/autoload`. But when I open the vim, it says that Plug is not a editor command.

What do I need to do to vim work?

PS: I'm using Windos and the command `:scriptnames` doesn't show autoload too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows you should use `~/vimfiles/` instead of `~/.vim/`.

I would suggest to use `~/vimfiles/vimrc` instead of `~/.vimrc` too.